# Cannot scroll to bottom of web page (WebKit on Windows)

Tags: css, webkit

I cannot scroll to the bottom of a web page I am working on. My `<body>` is styled with `overflow: auto` (which I believe is just normal web page default behavior). My content is narrow and tall so a vertical scroll bar is necessary. However, when I scroll as far as the scrollbar will let me, the bottom approx 40px of my content is clipped out of the viewport and there's no way to scroll any farther. A screenshot is below (the black is just my desktop background). The box in the bottom right corner is the scroll bar itself, but there's no down arrow below if for some reason and it won't go any further. The rounded rectangle on the left is the top bit of a cancel button that is clipped. This problem occurs on a WebKit based browser on Windows, but does not happen on the Mac.

Here's my CSS situation: `<body>` has overflow auto and 0 padding 0 margin.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: Can you post more of your CSS, as well as your HTML?

Comment: I'll see if I can extract a minimal amount and reproduce it in another context, but that will take me a while.

Comment: Without the code or an example it's going to be tough to answer this one.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm sure it's a combination of several things. Trying to extract an example now...

Comment: OK, so it turns out I cannot reproduce this given the exact same HTML/CSS using a standard Chrome for Windows build. Thus I conclude it's something about the embedded WebKit instance we are using in terms of configuration or maybe our build is just too old. Will delete this question as overly narrow.

Answer (score 2):

overflow: visible is the browsers default. I had to see more of your css to be able to help you, but, either way, try setting overflow to visible.

Though, I dont really think it will solve the issue. With overflow auto you should get a vertical scrollbar when the contents height is greater than the containing blocks height. That's not your case.

Answer (score 1):

i had problem like this before, I removed position: fixed on my header and its worked. Hope that help someone